# Sql query for select 2 result with 1 query

Tags: sql

I want to select 2 expected result with just 1 query, but i dont know how.

#### The data mostly like this

```
Id  Result  Order Id
1   10      Order_1
1   10      Order_2
2   30      Order_3
3   40      Order_4
```

nb :

```
- 1 Id only have 1 Result
- 1 Id can have more than 1 Order_Id
```

#### Expected result

```
Id  Result      Order Id
1   10          Order_1
2   30          Order_2
3   40          Order_3
                Order_4
```

#### My try

I try with "regular" sql as follow :

```
Id  Result  Order Id
**1 10      Order_1
1   10      Order_2**
2   30      Order_3
3   40      Order_4
```

from my sql, i cannot separate 1 id which having 2 Order_Id.
Actually, i dont need reference like 1 Id are having 2 Order_Id or something.
I only need all Order Id for all ID which i have.

Is it possible to do it by 1 query?
Because usually i get those result with 2 query.

Sorry for my bad english.
Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Is this `Order Id` a real field in a table? So for example, you have one record with `2 30 Order_3`, but you want it to be displayed as `2 30 Order_2` instead? It looks like you want a distinct of the first two columns and then to generate the `Order Id` column with `Order_` + row number. Is that correct?

Comment: What do you mean by "regular" SQL?

Comment: Do you want to have this result?
1   10      Order_1, Order_2
2   30      Order_3
3   40      Order_4

Comment: @All :
Actually there are 2 table.

=First table=
Id Result 
1 10
2 30
3 40
=Second table=
Order Id Id
Order_1 1
Order_2 1
Order_3 2
Order_4 3

my "Regular SQL" is:
Select a.id,a.result, b.order_id
from Id a join Order b on (a.id=b.id)

the result :
Id Result  Order Id
1 10         Order_1
1 10         Order_2
2 30         Order_3
3 40         Order_4

#Expected result are  :

Id Result 
1 10
2 30
3 40

and i get 
Order Id
Order_1
Order_2
Order_3
Order_4

is it possible to do it by 1 query insted of 2? because i usually get those result by using 2 query.